Moving data between old mysql and new proxySQL with 3 mysql nodes
I have old data in single mysql database (~700GB), and want to move to ProxySQL with 3 mysql nodes - separate 2 big big tables on node 2 and 3, while rest of data on node 1.
I readed how to do this by simply mysqldump, but I have lack of disk space, and dump didn't fit, so I wonder if there is another way to copy data.

You could run mysqldump from another server. For example mysqldump -h theIpOfTheServerWithDatabase ....

Different tables on each node?  Or different rows?  Or different columns?  Will the nodes have copies of all the same data?  Or will you need to JOIN tables from different nodes?  JOIN across nodes is terribly inefficient.

Different tables on 2 nodes - Do not need to JOIN
